# How can I delete duplicate rows when joining two tables and condition is met

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables in BigQuery with the following columns

t1

```
timestamp |customer_id |office |client_name
01.01.2020|1           |USA    |Mike
01.01.2020|2           |USA    |John
01.01.2020|3           |GER    |Jenny`
```

t2

```
timestamp |customer_id |agent_id |agent_role
01.01.2020|1           |10       |Level1
01.01.2020|1           |20       |Level2
01.01.2020|2           |30       |Level1`
```

Now when I join this two tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.timestamp, t2.customer_id, office, client_name,
        CASE WHEN role = "Leve1" THEN agent_id ELSE NULL END
        AS responsible_agent, 
FROM t1 
   LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
```

I get the following table

t3

```
timestamp |customer_id |office |client_name|agent_id
01.01.2020|1           |USA    |Mike       | 10
01.01.2020|1           |USA    |Mike       |null
01.01.2020|2           |USA    |Jenny      | 30`
```

My new table (t3) should display the agent_id if there is a Level 1 assigned, null if there is no Level 1 assigned and nothing more. 
As you can see in t3 i get two records for customer_id = 1 because customer_id = 1 has an agent_role = Level 1 but also a agent_role = Level 2 assigned.

t3

```
timestamp |customer_id |office |client_name|agent_id
01.01.2020|1           |USA    |Mike       | 10
01.01.2020|1           |USA    |Mike       |null
```

My quest is to join t1 and t2 .. display the agent_id if there is a Level 1 , display null if there is no Level 1 assigned and remove the ones that are display null because there is a Level 2 assigned.

Comment: Why do the sample results have `customer_id = 1` twice and no `customer_id = 2`?  That is not consistent with your description.

Comment: the second table is a db of all the agents that are assigned to customers.A customer can have a level 1 person and a level 2 person. In t2 im saying that customer 1 has a level1 and a level 2 assigned. t3 should be the results table. I omited customer_id = 2 because my point is to remove the nulls if they don;t come from the fact that customer_id has or has not a level 1 assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.customer_id, t1.office, t1.client_name,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN t2.role = 'Leve1' THEN t2.agent_id END) , 
                MAX(t2.agent_id)
               ) AS responsible_agent,
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
GROUP BY t1.timestamp, t1.customer_id, t1.office, t1.client_name;
```

Comment: understood it correctly .. this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.timestamp, t1.customer_id, office, client_name,t2.agent_id 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id AND t2.agent_role = 'Level1'
```

Comment: Please explain your solution a bit.